# Difference between wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout vs wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout

Tags: android, wear-os

I am new in the wearable world and trying to distinguish things.
Can anyone explain what is the difference between these two? I want to make my root layout of a WearableActivity fit the watch bounds. The official documentation is missing or incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official `android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/BoxInsetLayout.html):

> **This class is deprecated.**
>
> use the android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout provided by the Android
>   Support Library Wear module instead.